# The usage of one

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence is correct?

The ABC computational algorithm of the DD method is the same as the one of the CC method

What is the usage of one?

Comment: =  same as "that" of the CC method

Comment: could you share the research you have done?

Answer (score -1):

The ABC computational algorithm of the DD method is the same as the **one** of **the** CC method.

This sounds very technical. However, it looks/sounds to me that the author is stating that there is a similarity between two types of methods.

I would say that the author's use of **one** is being used to make the CC method specific.  In my view this is not necessary and sounds clumsy.
The use of the article **the** would quite as easily do the same job.
*
*Look at the example below**

The ABC computational algorithm of the DD method is the same as of **the** CC method.

I hope that sounds reasonable and helps.